# GEN 0 Garbage climbing on Azure is this normal?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, memory-leaks

After a week of running, our asp.net webapi web app on Azure becomes quite slow.  Rebooting the web app fixes the issue.

The only thing I can see that looks suspicious is the Gen 0 Garbage collection climbs constantly. Is this indicating a memory leak or is just showing the number of objects that are being deleted?

The nose dive in the image below is from when I restarted the web app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an indication of a memory leak.  It's also not anything specific to Azure.  Gen 0 collections will occur more often than Gen 1 and 2 - that's [the way the .NET GC works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) to satisfy memory requirements for the process.

Now, you could still have a memory leak somewhere in your application that is causing the performance degradation.  To troubleshoot this, I would recommend instrumenting your application with [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-performance) or a 3rd party APM tool to understand where the degradation is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the webjob list of your Web App if you have DaaS (diagnostic as a service).
We had this job running on our web apps, and after killing it, we no longer have GC Gen on our DotNet Core Web App...

[image: GC Collect]